# export facebook contacts to .csv

Tags: csv, facebook

I want to export all my facbeook contacts into .CSV format or any other contacts format

I have tried to import facebook contacts to yahoo mail then export both in .CSV but it didn't work with the new yahoo

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There appears to be [a facebook application](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=32853197098) that can do this for you. I'm uncertain if it actually works as I have not tested it.

Comment: link is not available

Answer (score 6):

If all you need is their name, you can call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[YOUR_USER_ID]/friends?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

with an application access token either from one of your current applications or the Facebook [access token tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

This will return the name and facebook ID of all your friends in JSON form that you can convert to .CSV by just looping through the data array.

If you need more than just their name and facebook id, you'll have to use FQL by calling:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_url FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

The full list of fields you can query in your SELECT can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/).

Comment: The links are 404 in this post.